# Vagrant + Virtualbox custom box: NAT adapter getting ipv6 address instead of ipv4

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm creating my own box for Vagrant using CentOS 6. When using the original box, there's only one adapter, the NAT. DHCP worked without problems, and the NAT interface got an IPv4 address. I was able to port-forward into the box for both SSH (22) and Web (80) ports.

However, after packaging the box and trying to "up" it for the first time, the interface gets an IPv6 address, and the port-forwarding doesn't work, not even manually configured using Virtualbox interface.

I'm out of ideas on why this happens. Didn't try to work around it tho, maybe assigning the IP address manually would do the trick, but I'm still curious on why now the Virtualbox DHCP is sending an IPv6 address.

**EDIT:**

Manually assigning an IP at the Vagrantfile solves the problem partially. But the IP is only assigned after I halt and up the box.

**EDIT2:**

And now, not even with halt and up it's getting the manually assigned ipv4 IP. Totally confused...

Answer (score 0):

You might be right about manually changing the IP. NAT is a hard requirement for vagrant so you will not get rid of that.

Add this to your Vagrantfile and see if it helps, set the IP to whatever is applicable for you

```
config.vm.network "your_network", ip: "192.xxx.xx.xx"
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick for now, but I'm still curious on why did this happen tho...